# Assigning function pointer to function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I've got a problem when trying to assign a function pointer to a function pointer in a struct.

I have a struct `command`, which holds an invocation string value, a message to acknowledge its activation, and a function to be called upon activation.

However, I am having trouble assigning the function pointer in the struct's constructor (might make the struct into a class later, not sure) below.

```
struct Command
{
    Command(string _code, string _message, void *_func(void))
        : code(_code), message(_message) { /* ERROR: */ func = _func; }

    string code;        // The string that invokes a console response
    string message;     // The response that is printed to acknowledge its activation
    void *func(void);   // The function that is run when the string is called
};
```

In the above code, marked by `/* ERROR: */` I get the error, `"expression must be a modifiable value"`. How can I fix this? I just want to pass a reference to a function to the struct.

Comment: `void *func(void)` is not a function pointer, it's a declaration of a function named `func` which takes no arguments and return a `void*`. `void (*func)(void)` is a variable named `func` which is a pointer to a function taking no arguments and returning nothing.

Comment: Also, in C++ you should be careful with pointers to functions, as those can only be used for non-member functions, static member function or one type of lambda expression. If you want a more generic function-type, read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Ugh, you're right. Cool man, thanks for the answer! Works now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383353/assigning-function-pointer-to-function-pointer#comment41421026_26383353) you don't declare a pointer to a function.

To declare a function pointer you need to add parentheses around the asterisk and identifier part, e.g.

```
// 'func' is a pointer to function taking parameter void and returning void.
void (*func)(void);
```

Since C++11 you can also declare a function pointer like this which is less terse:

```
std::add_pointer_t<void()> func;

std::add_pointer_t<void(int, int)> func; // Pointer to func taking 2 ints.
```

Comment: After a quick messaround I don't fully understand add_pointer nor how to use std::function for my purposes. I'll have to look into that further. Until then, thanks for the quick fix :D

Comment: You can simply replace all occurences of `void (*func)(void)` with `std::add_pointer_t<void()> func` with no subsequent change in behaviour. Also remember that in C++ you don't have to declare a parameter list that takes nothing with `(void)`, instead you can simply do `()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need brackets around *func and *_func